# Multer isn't saving to specified destination

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer

I'm fairly new to nodejs/ express, but no matter what I seem to do I cant seem to get multer to save to the specified destination, it seems to completely ignore the parameter all together.  The code is shown below

```
//app.js
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var apiRouter = express.Router();
var app = express();

var store = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function(req,file,cb){
    console.log("filename");
    cb(null, Date.now()+'.'+file.originalname);
  },
  desitnation: function(req,file,cb){
    console.log("storage");
    cb(null,'./public/');
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage:store}).single('file');

apiRouter.post('/upload', function(req, res){
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.end(err.toString());
    }
    console.log(req.file);
    return res.json({originalname:req.file.originalname, uploadname:req.file.filename});
  });
});
```

The response I get when uploading is shown below:

```
GET /vendor.js.map 200 3.916 ms - 6636755
filename
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'Desert.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'C:\\Users\\Dwyer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
  filename: '1538979138829.Desert.jpg',
  path:
   'C:\\Users\\Dwyer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1538979138829.Desert.jpg',
  size: 845941 }
POST /api/upload 200 70.031 ms - 69
```

It seems to be setting the file correctly, but I'm not sure where it gets the destination from, no3 do I understand why the destination parameter isn't being read.

Answer (score 1):

> but no matter what I seem to do I cant seem to get multer to save to the specified destination, it seems to completely ignore the parameter all together.

This is because there seem to be a typo in the configuration.

```
'use strict';

var store = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log("filename");
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname);
  },
  destination: function (req, file, cb) { // it is destination not desitnation :)
    console.log("storage");
    cb(null, './public/');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its actually "destination" (not desitnation). You should also make sure that you have a folder ,with the specified name, at the specified destination.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try using physical address in destination? I guess destination in [multer document](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage) is physical address in linux os.

Comment: This is a Windows OS, but it doesn't seem to even enter the function, it never outputs "storage"